# My object is not transparent even when screen space refractions are turned on

Tags: transparency

I'm following a "glitch" effect tutorial (blender 2.91, rendering in EEVEE - not sure which version he's using although it has to be close and he's also in eevee)

[image: glitch tut']

This image is at the point where he has the text with the emission, and it's behind an edited icosphere (subdivided in editing, then back to object mode and scaled a bit).

Then he moves to add a new material in the lefthand panel. Adds new material, puts the roughness at 0, transmission at 1, turns on *screen space refractions* and gets this.

[image: now the icosphere is transparent]

But my icosphere is still not transparent

[image: My icosphere is still not transparent.]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your material settings, scroll down to "Blend Mode" and choose anything other than _Opaque_.